# Android 11 Package Visibilty issue

Tags: java, android, android-11

I have a app that downloads an apk from server, but I am unable to launch it like other android versions even though I have queries tag in android manifest

Here is the intent code:-

```
private void callInstallProcess() {
        try
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            File file = new File(pathname);
            Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
//            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
//                fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getPackageName(),
//                        file);
//            }
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=24){
                try{
                    Method m = StrictMode.class.getMethod("disableDeathOnFileUriExposure");
                    m.invoke(null);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            intent.setDataAndType(fileUri , "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            startActivityForResult(intent, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="x.x.x">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.android.package-archive" />
    </intent>
</queries>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/appicon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"

        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Gradle file:-

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0-rc4"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "x.x.x"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 'R'
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.11"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

I have allowed to my app the permission to install unknown apps on android R preview 4 emulator.

Log:-

```
W/System.err: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/x.x.x/files/ApkDownload/x.x.x.apk typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive flg=0x3 }
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:2067)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1727)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5323)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5281)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
        at x.x.x.MainActivity.callInstallProcess(MainActivity.java:126)
        at x.x.x.MainActivity.askPerm(MainActivity.java:98)
W/System.err:     at x.x.x.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:42)
        at x.x.x.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:79)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:167)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7478)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe8ae0220: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xe8e31210)
```

I am using android studio 4 and gradleversion is 4.0.0
Is it just a bug or am I doing something wrong as chrome manages to intent apk install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it just a bug or am I doing something wrong

You are doing something wrong.

`Uri.fromFile()` has been banned, in effect, since Android 7.0. Normally, your attempt to us it with an `Intent` would crash with a `FileUriExposedException`. Rather than fixing the problem, you decided to try to bypass the check, through your `disableDeathOnFileUriExposure` hack. However, *nobody else has to honor your `file:///` `Uri`*, because, again, that has been banned for years. Apparently, Android R's installer no longer supports `file:///`.

So, at minimum, you need to switch to using `FileProvider` on Android 7.0+. `Uri.fromFile()` is fine for Android 6.0 and older, and specifically for what you are trying to do (install an APK), you have no choice but to use `Uri.fromFile()` for those older devices.

Also note that using `ACTION_VIEW` for installing an APK has been deprecated on Android 10+. Temporarily it still works, but Google would like you to switch to the `PackageInstaller` API instead.

Comment: Can you provide code or links on how to use package installer as whenever I search for package installer, questions for silent installs popup which require device owner permission.

Comment: @saksham: [This sample](https://gitlab.com/commonsguy/cw-android-q/-/tree/vFINAL/AppInstaller) shows using `PackageInstaller`. Note that it is in Kotlin -- I do not have a Java equivalent of that sample.